# OpenGL/webGL not working, nouveau drivers

Tags: drivers, opengl, hardware-acceleration, display-driver

Title says it, OpenGL software crashes and Chromium says hardware acceleration is not available for webGL, though they should be supported by nouveau drivers.

Running 64-bit Arch linux with xfce4 desktop. I have mesa, xf86-video-nouveau, nouveau-dri and lib32-nouveau-dri packages installed. Am I missing some package?

```
$ inxi -Gx
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GF114 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
       X.Org: 1.14.3 driver: nouveau Resolution: 1280x1024@60.0hz 
       GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NVCE GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.0 Direct Rendering: Yes

$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NVCE
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 9.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

Comment: Have you reported the crashes to the developers?

Answer (score -1):

Probably the best thing to do to get full 3D support is to use the proprietary drivers:

```
pacman -S nvidia
```

They update in lock-step with the official kernel packages so your system won't break on you.